# MySQL query to retrieve DISTINCT COUNT between moving DATE period

Tags: mysql, sql, count, distinct, between

I'm trying to write a query that returns a list of dates and the DISTINCT COUNT of User IDs for the 7 days preceding each date. The table I'm working with is simple, and looks like this:

```
Started                 UserId
"2012-09-25 00:01:04"   164382
"2012-09-25 00:01:39"   164382
"2012-09-25 00:02:37"   166121
"2012-09-25 00:03:35"   155682
"2012-09-25 00:04:18"   160947
"2012-09-25 00:08:19"   165806
```

I can write the query for output of an individual COUNT as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT UserId)
FROM Session 
WHERE Started BETWEEN '2012-09-18 00:00' AND '2012-09-25 00:00';
```

But what I'm trying to do is output this COUNT for every day in the table AND the 7 days preceding it. To clarify, the value for September 25th would be the count of DISTINCT User IDs between the 18th and 25th, the 24th the count between 17th and 24th, etc.

I tried the following query but it provides just the COUNT for each day:

```
SELECT 
DATE(A.Started),
Count(DISTINCT A.UserId)
FROM Session AS A
WHERE DATE(A.Started) BETWEEN DATE(DATE_SUB(DATE(DATE(A.Started)),INTERVAL 7 DAY)) AND DATE(DATE(A.Started))
GROUP BY DATE(A.Started)
ORDER BY DATE(A.Started);
```

And the output looks like this:

```
DATE(A.Started) "Count(DISTINCT A.UserId)"
2012-09-18          709
2012-09-19          677
2012-09-20          658
2012-09-21          556
2012-09-22          530
2012-09-23          479
2012-09-24          528
2012-09-25          480
...
```

But as I said, those are just the daily counts. Initially I thought I could just sum the 7 day values, but that will invalidate the DISTINCT clause. **I need the DISTINCT UserId counts for each 7 day period preceding a given date.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should work for you:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(d1.Started, '%Y-%m-%d') AS Started,
    COUNT(DISTINCT d2.UserID) Users
FROM
(
    SELECT
        DATE(Started) AS Started
    FROM
        Session
    GROUP BY
        DATE(Started)
) d1 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        DATE(Started) AS Started,
        UserID
    FROM
        Session
) d2
ON d2.Started BETWEEN d1.Started - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND d1.Started
GROUP BY
    d1.Started
ORDER BY
    d1.Started DESC
```

Visit http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9339c/5 to see this query in action.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't seem to be quite right though. It's correct for the most recent day, but then the user count increases as you go further back in time. This should not be the case. The same is visible in the SQLFiddle example you gave. The user count should be for a sliding 7 day window. What seems to be happening though is the query is summing ALL distinct users, starting from the last 7 days, but then gradually increasing the window to cover all time. The final count I get for the oldest date in the system is exactly equal to all distinct users that exist in the system.

Comment: That's because of the way the sample data was loaded. When we load the data uniformally, as done in http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/33deb/1 , the   count doesn't increase.

Comment: What changes do I need to make then for the query work for my data set? I'm working with a 90,000 row table. At this point I can't really restructure it without causing major headaches.

Comment: I updated the answer. Please try it again. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Accepted. I'll upvote as soon as I have a high enough reputation. The login changes StackOverflow made recently locked me out of my old account - Now I have to start from scratch :(

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
Select Distinct Date(A.Started), Count(B.UserId)
From Session a
    Join Session b 
        On b.Start Between AddDate(A.Start, day, -7) And A.Start
```

I'm not a MySQL guy, so the syntax might not be correct, but the pattern will work....

Comment: Charles, since you're missing a `GROUP BY`, this query only returns a single record. See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dafc3/3